# Elastic search MongoDB Integration tool suggestion

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, synchronization

I want to synchronize MongoDB cluster with Elastic Search 6.x. I've used mongo-connector before that reads oplog and it was very successful. But it haven't received any commit for 1 years and not supporting the Elastic Search v 6.x. Can you suggest a tool that can synchronize billions of records.
Thnx.

Comment: i suggest you to look at Logstash that parts of the ELK Stack.
İt also has https://github.com/phutchins/logstash-input-mongodb plugin to read from mongodb and export to elasticsearch.

Comment: Thanks @devquy. I'll test it for performance. In documentation it says it also reads oplog like mongo-connector.